# How to read the biometric scanner device input in java

Tags: java, biometrics

I am new to Biometrics scanner devices worikng protocols, I am working on  Biometric project, in that i have to read biometrics which are are taking by the connected biometric scanners in the application, but i dont know how we can detect those devices in java, & read the input dynamically & verify that is exist in out CIDR or not. Please could anyone please help me out , how to read the biometric scanners input & how to detect those in our java class?

Comment: You could _at least_ tell us, how those device are connected to your machine ... RS/232, TCP/IP, carrier pigeon ?

Comment: I too am looking out for the same. Read the output of a biometric scanner for android. Anyone with useful information please help